# File sharing options in TFS2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

All,

We're thinking of migrating our existing VSS sourcecode to TFS2010 but there is one big block. We cannot share source between multiple solutions.

We need this for good reason - we have a large common code base in the "server" world with our "mobile" world, but we need different VS project files to be able to compile either in a server platform or a mobile platform.

VSS shared files was a neat solution to maintaining a single code base.

Unfortunately that option doesn't exist in TFS 2010 and branching doesn't really do what we want as the files are not actually shared.

Has anybody any ideas how we can get round this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple solutions sharing some projects may be you can check [Chapter 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668953.aspx) "Structuring Projects and Solutions in Source Control" and then [Chapter 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668960.aspx) "Large Project Considerations
" of the "Team Development with Visual Studio Team Foundation Server" guide, a little oldie but still useful advice on setting up unusual source code scenarios like yours.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same shoe and the closest solution I'm looking into is to use the codeplex source code http://tfsfilesharer.codeplex.com/ work for TFS2010.

Thought it might help someone out in the wild :)